# once more: .htaccess - RewriteRules working, but browser address bar displaying full (unfriendly) URL

Tags: .htaccess

I can't seem to find my problem with this really simple `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /d/
`#`drupal style url rewriting
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

It works as intended for everything except the root url with no slash. So it rewrites and passes the hidden get querystring to my pages for `localhost/d/x/y/z` as `?path=x/y/z` and `localhost/d/` as `?path= (blank)` but `localhost/d` works, but now appears in the address bar as this ugly monster:

```
http://localhost/d/?path=/Users/audiozoom/Documents/webroot/d
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding a conditional rule to the top.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /d$`

`RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]`

But i don't like it at all there since now I have the base folder twice in my htaccess. Maybe someone will find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[QSA]` to the end of your rule. This will quietly pass the entire query string.

Comment: didn't work. this whole querystring is strange too. normally it displays everything after the path to my site root.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your PHP code doesn't redirect the request. Your rewrite rule says `index.php?path=` but the URL you see is `?path=`. That may be caused by a redirection.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a test folder with only 2 files: .htaccess with only the code above and index.php where the only line is `echo "path is: ".$_GET['path'];` to make sure that your suggestion isn't the case.